# Youtube Watchme android application error

Tags: android, api, youtube-api, live-streaming, youtube-livestreaming-api

I am new to android development.I am developing android application using https://github.com/youtube/yt-watchme. When start the live streaming it's closing unexpectedly. And in my android studio console I am getting the following error.

```
09-18 10:33:26.427  16692-16692/? E/AndroidRuntime﹕ FATAL EXCEPTION: main
    Process: com.google.android.apps.watchme, PID: 16692
    java.lang.UnsatisfiedLinkError: Couldn't load Ffmpeg from loader dalvik.system.PathClassLoader[DexPathList[[zip file "/data/app/com.google.android.apps.watchme-2.apk"],nativeLibraryDirectories=[/data/app-lib/com.google.android.apps.watchme-2, /vendor/lib, /system/lib]]]: findLibrary returned null
            at java.lang.Runtime.loadLibrary(Runtime.java:358)
            at java.lang.System.loadLibrary(System.java:526)
            at com.google.android.apps.watchme.Ffmpeg.<clinit>(Ffmpeg.java:26)
            at com.google.android.apps.watchme.VideoStreamingConnection.open(VideoStreamingConnection.java:71)
            at com.google.android.apps.watchme.StreamerService.startStreaming(StreamerService.java:80)
            at com.google.android.apps.watchme.StreamerActivity.startStreaming(StreamerActivity.java:212)
            at com.google.android.apps.watchme.StreamerActivity.access$200(StreamerActivity.java:47)
            at com.google.android.apps.watchme.StreamerActivity$1.onServiceConnected(StreamerActivity.java:64)
            at android.app.LoadedApk$ServiceDispatcher.doConnected(LoadedApk.java:1110)
            at android.app.LoadedApk$ServiceDispatcher$RunConnection.run(LoadedApk.java:1127)
            at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:733)
            at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:95)
            at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:136)
            at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5097)
            at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
            at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:515)
            at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:785)
            at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:601)
            at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
```

Please help me to solve this issue. I am really stuck with this issue.

Updated code:

```
/*
 * Copyright (c) 2014 Google Inc.
 *
 * Licensed under the Apache License, Version 2.0 (the "License"); you may not use this file except
 * in compliance with the License. You may obtain a copy of the License at
 *
 * http://www.apache.org/licenses/LICENSE-2.0
 *
 * Unless required by applicable law or agreed to in writing, software distributed under the License
 * is distributed on an "AS IS" BASIS, WITHOUT WARRANTIES OR CONDITIONS OF ANY KIND, either express
 * or implied. See the License for the specific language governing permissions and limitations under
 * the License.
 */

package com.google.android.apps.watchme;

/**
 * @author Ibrahim Ulukaya <ulukaya@google.com>
 *         <p/>
 *         FFmpeg class which loads ffmpeg library and exposes its methods.
 */
public class Ffmpeg {


    static {
        System.loadLibrary("ffmpeg");
    }

    public static native boolean init(int width, int height, int audio_sample_rate, String rtmpUrl);

    public static native void shutdown();

    // Returns the size of the encoded frame.
    public static native int encodeVideoFrame(byte[] yuv_image);

    public static native int encodeAudioFrame(short[] audio_data, int length);
}
```

Answer (score 2):

You should compile *FFmpeg* library and place in **src/main/jniLibs/armeabi** as native library app tries to load 

`System.loadLibrary("ffmpeg");`

Comment: Yes, i am using System.loadLibrary("ffmpeg"); code in Ffmpeg.java file I updated code in my above section. Anything wrong in there?

Comment: you do not have compiled ffmpeg.so files

Comment: What can i do for that? I a,m new to android development .can you please explain

Comment: there is a post here for you how to compile FFmpeg for Android: https://vec.io/posts/how-to-build-ffmpeg-with-android-ndk

Comment: I am using windows machine with android studio.how can i do these changes for android studio?

Answer (score -1):

I think you only import Jni library you need to import other library also that .so files,[Click Here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/3oaC9.png)

Comment: While this link may answer the question, it is better to include the essential parts of the answer here and provide the link for reference.  Link-only answers can become invalid if the linked page changes. - [From Review](/review/low-quality-posts/14043048)

Comment: In this link you can see screenshot and library which you need for youtube live streaming.